# Prove sets using logic laws

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

Prove $(A \cup B) \times C = (A \times C) \cup (B \times C).$
Where A,B and C are sets

I need it using logic laws?

Comment: Hello, welcome to the site. Please let us know what you have tried to do. Mainly because there are many ways with dealing with sets like these. Do you have the De Morgan's laws?

Comment: Ya I know how to convert the unions and intersections to logical connectives but what about the ×?

Comment: What is $A\times B$? Can you adequately describe it?

Comment: A,B and C are sets so it's two sets multiplying each other.Cartesian product

Comment: So specifically $A\times B := \{(a,b)| a\in A \: \mathrm{and}\:b\in B\}$. Can you write the set notation for $(A\cup B)\times C$?

Comment: What's the point of converting it into sets notations cos i need to prove it using logic laws?

Comment: It would help in showing that you know what you need to be proven. And yes it would help tremendously as it would change the problem into a problem of logic instead of a problem of sets. Showing what you've tried so far indicates what level you're on - otherwise it's impossible to adapt the answer to your level and to actually help you with what exactly you have problem with.

Comment: What are your "logic laws" about sets?  I don't know what you are asking.

Comment: Like De Morgan's law,commutative laws and such so it's written using connectives like V in place of intersection.

Comment: We did you post the exact same question twice?

Comment: Yes... Yes he did... This means this question is most likely going to be closed.

Answer (score 1):

$$(A\cup B)\times C=\{x|x\in A\cup B\}\times C=\{x|x\in A\lor x\in B\}\times C$$

$$(A\times C)\cup(B\times C)=(\{x|x\in A\}\times C)\cup (\{x|x\in B\}\times C)$$

Now we have to convince ourselves that the right most representations for each expression are indeed the same, i.e.

$$\{x|x\in A\lor x\in B\}\times C=(\{x|x\in A\}\times C)\cup (\{x|x\in B\}\times C)$$

We can do this by examining the definition of the Cartesian product:

$$X\times Y=\{(x,y)|x\in X \land y\in Y\}$$

So we have:

$$\{x|x\in A\lor x\in B\}\times C=\{(x,c)|(x\in A\lor x\in B)\land c\in C\}$$

$$(\{x|x\in A\}\times C)\lor (\{x|x\in B\}\times C)=\{(x,c)|x\in A\land c\in C\}\cup \{(x,c)|x\in B\land c\in C\}$$

As the logical disjunction and logical conjunction operators are distributive, and using:

$$\{x|x\in A\cup B\}=\{x|x\in A\}\cup \{x|x\in B\}$$

we have proved the identity.